# How to cluster Points with ST_ClusterDBSCAN taking into account their type stored in a separate column?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering

I was looking to use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` on a set of points that also have a type. So I want the points to be clustered by type, so that points having different types won't end up in the same cluster. Since `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` is windowed function I thought I could simply `PARTITION BY type` column and that will do. Something like:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(point, eps := 20, minpoints := 3) OVER(PARTITION BY type) AS cid,
```

However I still end up having same `cid` assigned to points of different type.

[image]

Obviously there's something I misunderstand either about clustering or windowed functions in general?

`ST_ClusterDBSCAN` assigns `cid`s differently with and without of `PARTITION BY type` so partitioning definitely affects the outcome somehow, I'm just not sure how exactly. Obviously not the way one would expect.

Comment: maybe records 2 and 3 are more than 20 units away from eachother so they would never be in a cluster regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster IDs are unique to each partition. You can read about how window functions work [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: Are you sure about `cluster IDs are unique to each partition` part? Or it's just guess? I mean I came to the same conclusion, but would great to have a confirmation from some official doc.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You can read the documentation I linked to in the answer.